# Multiple domain linking to one existing domain

Tags: php, multiple-domains

I have an existing site almost 85%  of its contents are database driven, Now I want 50 more such sites. I have an Idea of using this site as base site and access this site from different domains. I can keep database different for each domain. All of these websites behave and work as independent sites , except the fact, that these all  is actually using a single site with  their own database .

Now Is this a feasible idea ? what are the Pros and cons of this approach ? Is there an issue of Google blocking these sites arise ?

I have given one more option of keeping centralized database for sites and  keep there code in respective domains.

I am confused as am also a newbie in PHP and web development.

I found some breakthrough here [.htaccess RewriteRule: two domains using same server and directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972413/htaccess-rewriterule-two-domains-using-same-server-and-directory)
now I have to see about Google issue

Thanks

Comment: Surely you want both a shared codebase *and* a shared databases. Duplicating either will make maintenance a nightmare. Add a "sites" table to your database, and update your application to be site-aware.

Comment: One application, One codebase, One database, 50 sites.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using one site for multiple domain in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569466/using-one-site-for-multiple-domain-in-php) - Please don't duplicate questions.

Comment: yes I did added this question yesterday I have entirely different approach and issues today, please bear with me I am not getting exact answer of my problem , I need easy answer in straight forward manner

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: One Codebase , 50 site and 50 database

Comment: Google would lower your rating if you had lots of duplicate content across multiple domains.

Comment: "I want quick replicate" is not good england, please try again

Comment: Sorry I am not native English speaker , so please excuse my language , I will not have duplicate  contents more then 5% in each sites as all contents are coming from their respective database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big con is the duplication of comments (as mentioned in the comments).

If `domain1.com` has contains the same, or all most the same content as `domain2.com` Google gives both sites a penalty which will result in in lower rating. Keep in mind that the same happens if you duplicate content over multiple pages in a website. (`domain1.com/page1` having the same content as `domain1.com/page2`).

If the 50 site have unique contents this won't be a problem.

Comment: Roel these  are going to be unique contents site , only codebase is same. let me give you example I own a abcuniversity.com and it is  kind of search plateform for its student so all data is related to abcuniversity , now i want xyzuniversity.com for same purpose , so you can see contents are not same at all .... Thanks

Comment: @phpfighter, only con could then be that if you make one mistake with updating code all 50 sites are down.